# When I open XAMPP and click MySQL start button it gives me an error. I had started it just before, but now it isn't working

Tags: mysql, xampp

When I open XAMPP and click on MySQL start  button it starts for a second and then ends and gives me an error. I had started it before, but now it isn't working.

```
    enter code here

14:28:03  [mysql]   Status change detected: stopped
14:28:03  [mysql]   Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
14:28:03  [mysql]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
14:28:03  [mysql]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
14:28:03  [mysql]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
14:28:03  [mysql]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
14:28:03  [mysql]   If you need more help, copy and post this
14:28:03  [mysql]   entire log window on the forums

Here is the contents of the error log:

2020-06-16 14:16:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2020-06-16 14:16:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-06-16 14:16:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-06-16 14:16:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-06-16 14:16:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2020-06-16 14:16:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2020-06-16 14:16:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-06-16 14:16:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2020-06-16 14:16:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-06-16 14:16:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-06-16 14:16:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-06-16 14:16:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-06-16 14:16:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.11 started; log sequence number 374114; transaction id 536
2020-06-16 14:16:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2020-06-16 14:16:16 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-06-16 14:16:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200616 14:16:16
2020-06-16 14:16:16 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
InnoDB: using atomic writes.
2020-06-16 14:28:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: The first innodb_system data file 'ibdata1' did not exist. A new tablespace will be created!
2020-06-16 14:28:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2020-06-16 14:28:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-06-16 14:28:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-06-16 14:28:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-06-16 14:28:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2020-06-16 14:28:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2020-06-16 14:28:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-06-16 14:28:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibdata1' size to 10 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-06-16 14:28:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibdata1' size is now 10 MB.
2020-06-16 14:28:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting log file C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile101 size to 5242880 bytes
2020-06-16 14:28:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting log file C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile1 size to 5242880 bytes
2020-06-16 14:28:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: Renaming log file C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile101 to C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile0
2020-06-16 14:28:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: New log files created, LSN=11452
2020-06-16 14:28:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: Doublewrite buffer not found: creating new
2020-06-16 14:28:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: Doublewrite buffer created
2020-06-16 14:28:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2020-06-16 14:28:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating foreign key constraint system tables.
2020-06-16 14:28:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating tablespace and datafile system tables.
2020-06-16 14:28:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating sys_virtual system tables.
2020-06-16 14:28:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-06-16 14:28:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-06-16 14:28:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-06-16 14:28:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-06-16 14:28:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.11 started; log sequence number 0; transaction id 7
2020-06-16 14:28:00 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-06-16 14:28:00 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

I looked for a similar problem in stackoverflow and I try to delete the **ibdata1** file in mysql\data directory, but nothing happened. Could someone help me,please?

I have changed the port to 33060,and restart the XAMPP but still isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Go to C:\xampp\mysql\

Windows has a feature to restore previous version of folder.

Right click on **Data** folder and go to **Restore previous version**.

Restore it to the time when it was working properly.

This helped me.

But it may cause to lose some of your table and configurations due to restoring. And you may have to create users, grants and privileges again.

To prevent such mishapps you should run XAMPP as administrator.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but it says: no previous versions available :(